# MYSQL update with joins

Tags: mysql

When running the query :

```
UPDATE video v,akadam_post a,location l 
SET v.location_id=l.id 
WHERE a.encoding_id=v.id AND l.continentCode=a.loc_continent_code AND 
l.countryCode=a.loc_country_code AND l.regionCode=a.loc_region_code AND 
l.cityCode=a.loc_city_code
```

I get a syntax error, any idea ?

```
10:04:02    select id,encoding_id from akadam_post a left join location l on l.continentCode=a.loc_continent_code AND l.countryCode=a.loc_country_code AND l.regionCode=a.loc_region_code AND l.cityCode=a.loc_city_code  UPDATE video v,akadam_post a,location l SET v.location_id=l.id  WHERE a.encoding_id=v.id AND l.continentCode=a.loc_continent_code AND l.countryCode=a.loc_country_code AND l.regionCode=a.loc_region_code AND l.cityCode=a.loc_city_code  Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE video v,akadam_post a,location l SET v.location_id=l.id  WHERE a.encoding' at line 3    0.00051 sec
```

Thanks !

Comment: Have you hired the error from a different query?

Comment: Nothing specific stands out. Can you share table structures (column names and key columns) for the three tables involved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is not correct and it should as

```
update video v
join akadam_post a on a.encoding_id=v.id
join location l on l.continentCode=a.loc_continent_code 
and l.countryCode=a.loc_country_code and l.regionCode=a.loc_region_code
and l.cityCode=a.loc_city_code
set v.location_id=l.id
```

Comment: The issue was comming from MySQLworkbench, firing the statement using the command line resolved the issue. I suspect an hidden special char in the string.